# Why I get the errors when the `git push origin master` command is working?

Tags: git, git-push

I am learning git. I use the [Git for Windows](http://git-for-windows.github.io/).
Why I get the errors when the `git push origin master` command is working?

I have written the script (BAT-file) for showing of this problem:

```
:: script.bat
::======================
:: Git repositories host
set host=d:/sandbox
:: Virtual disk name
set disk=v:

subst %disk% %host%
cd /D %disk%/

:: create some "remote" repository
set origin=v:\server
mkdir %origin%

set git="C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe"

call %git% init %origin%
echo aaa > "%origin%/a.txt"
echo bbb > "%origin%/b.txt"
echo ccc > "%origin%/c.txt"

cd %origin%
call %git% add "*"
call %git% commit -m "Initialized"

:: clone our "remote" repository
set client1=%disk%\client-1

call %git% clone "%origin%" "%client1%"

cd "%client1%"
call %git% remote -v

echo ddd > "%client1%/d.txt"
call %git% add "./d.txt"
call %git% commit -m "./d.txt file added"
call %git% status

:: here is the problem...
call %git% push origin master

subst /D %disk%
```

I get such output:

```
C:\Users\bushm>D:\sandbox\script.bat

C:\Users\bushm>set host=d:/sandbox

C:\Users\bushm>set disk=v:

C:\Users\bushm>subst v: d:/sandbox

C:\Users\bushm>cd /D v:/

v:\>set origin=v:\server

v:\>mkdir v:\server

v:\>set git="C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe"

v:\>call "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" init v:\server
Initialized empty Git repository in v:/server/.git/

v:\>echo aaa  1>"v:\server/a.txt"

v:\>echo bbb  1>"v:\server/b.txt"

v:\>echo ccc  1>"v:\server/c.txt"

v:\>cd v:\server

v:\server>call "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" add "*"

v:\server>call "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" commit -m "Initialized"
[master (root-commit) 49f7952] Initialized
 3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 a.txt
 create mode 100644 b.txt
 create mode 100644 c.txt

v:\server>set client1=v:\client-1

v:\server>cd "v:\"

v:\>call "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" clone "v:\server" "v:\client-1"
Cloning into 'v:\client-1'...
done.

v:\>cd "v:\client-1"

v:\client-1>call "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" remote -v
origin  v:\server (fetch)
origin  v:\server (push)

v:\client-1>echo ddd  1>"v:\client-1/d.txt"

v:\client-1>call "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" add "./d.txt"

v:\client-1>call "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" commit -m "./d.txt file adde
d"
[master b6a43f1] ./d.txt file added
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 d.txt

v:\client-1>call "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

v:\client-1>call "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 278 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsist
ent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to matc
h
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to

remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into

remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some

remote: error: other way.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set

remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To v:\server
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'v:\server'

v:\client-1>subst /D v:

v:\client-1>
```

Why I get these errors?

Comment: Is your remote a non bare repo?

Comment: I don't understand you, Tim. :(

Comment: How did you initialize the remote repo? `git init` or `git init --bare`?

Comment: I used the `git init` command for my remote repository.

Comment: I believe it's because you still have the master branch checked out on the 'server'.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your server is not a bare repo, and you have the master branch checked out there.